# Multiples queries in meth app.post

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I need to render in a single page several query returns, for example:

1) students per neighborhood

2) student average

```
app.get('/gerais',(req,res) => {
const client = new Client();
client.connect()
    .then(() => {
        return client.query('SELECT COUNT(name) studentsperneighborhood,'
        +' neigh FROM student INNER JOIN adress ON student.adress_id =' 
        +'adress.id GROUP BY neigh');

    })
    .then((results) => {
        console.log('results?',results);
        res.render('general-info',results);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('error',err);
        res.send('FAIL');
    });
});
```

how could I modify the return, to return another query?

Comment: Do you want to insert new queries on this connection or do you want to change the sql query code?

Comment: i want returning multiples queries results.
something like 'return client.query('query1'),client.query('query2');'

Comment: I user `async` and `await` for multiple queries. I'll state an answer and you test.

Comment: Ok I'll revise my answer then post again.

Comment: So I tested my answer and it's correct, see what I did in my code just to test `async` and `await`. 
[Code Image](https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/stack2-jpg) and Postman
[Postman](https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/postmanimage-jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try running the queries separately and pass the results of both the queries in different objects.

Then render your page and inject these objects there to use them.
for eg. if you are using ejs file:-
then 
for eg:-

```
    connect.query('query1',function(err1, data1){
    connect.query('query2',function(err2, data2){

res.render('studentsinfo.ejs',{
       studentsperneighborhood: data1,
       studentaverage: data2
      })})})
```

Now, you use use these 2 objects to display your data.